# Jupyter: how to plot multiple histograms each with a fixed height?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter

I have a data frame with multiple columns and I'd like to plot the histograms of them all at once. The DataFrame object has a very nice `subplots` parameters to plot each variable in its own axes:

```
%matplotlib inline # same problem with %matplotlib notebook
df.iloc[:,-3:].plot.hist(subplots=True);
```

gives me:

[image: 3 histograms]

The problem is when I try to plot a greater number of columns:

```
%matplotlib inline
# 15 variables
df.iloc[:,-15:].plot.hist(subplots=True);
```

[image: Ugly multiple columns]

I'd like to be able to set a fixed height of each axes, and to have a very big image, or to be able to scroll to see them all.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to extend the vertical dimension of your figure with a call to `plt.subplots()` before the plot, like this:

```
nvars = 12  # Example number of variables

# subplots(number of vertically stacked axis positions,
#          number of horizontally stacked axis positions,
#          figsize=(width, height))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nvars, 1, figsize=(6, 4*nvars))

# Need to pass axis handle to df.plot()
df.iloc[:,-nvars:].plot.hist(subplots=True, ax=ax);
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `df.iloc[:,-nvars:]` ?